# Getting chapter and section in \fancyhead

Tags: sectioning, chapters, fancyhdr

I am having a bit of a heard time getting `\fancyhead` to give me the out put I want. I'd like to have a header that includes Chapter X: THIS IS THE SECTION (italicized like the default). I can get it to do chapter centred and section in the right but It'd be cool if they could be on the right together. I ahve a feeling I can do this with a `\renewcommand` but I can't find the combination that works. Alternatively if anyone knows how to combine `\thechapter` and `\rightmark` within `\fancyhead` that would help too.

Currently I'm using:

`\fancyhead[R]{\textit{ \nouppercase{\thechapter}} }`

in a multi-chapter report document with `\pagestyle{fancy}` in the preamble.

This gives me "Chapter 2" in the header but I would like "Chapter 2: Experimental Methods"

Thanks in advance and I'm still pretty new at this so let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Have you tried `\leftmark` instead of `\thechapter`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @egreg. That give the Chapter and chapter title, which is quite long sometime as this is for my thesis. `\rightmark` gives the section but not the chapter... I think I should be able to `\renewcommand` `\rightmark` or `\leftmark` but no combination that I've tried works

Comment: Usually only information about either the current chapter or section goes in a header, as they need space. The most common way is to have chapter information on left pages (even) and section information on right pages (odd). If your thesis is one-sided, then choose chapters.

Comment: @egreg OK. I guess I'm being too picky. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: You *might* use two lines, but this is quite heavy. Can you supplement your question with more information?

Comment: Since I'm still pretty new at this,  what type of information would you like? I can try to provide a MWE but really the preamble only has `\pagestyle{fancy}` and that's it. I tried doing two lines like:

`\fancyhead[R]{\textit{\scriptsize{ \nouppercase{Chapter \thechapter}} }}`
`\fancyhead[R]{\textit{\scriptsize{ \nouppercase{\rightmark}} }}`

But the second line overwrites the first

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8722/discussion-between-ubuntingbiochemist-and-egreg)

Answer (score 4):

Usually only information about either the current chapter or section goes in a header, as they need space. The most common way is to have chapter information on left pages (even) and section information on right pages (odd). If your thesis is one-sided, then choose chapters

A possible way out is to use two lines in the header, but be careful because it might get too heavy.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[R]{\footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}
    \nouppercase{\leftmark}\\[3pt]
    \nouppercase{\rightmark}
  \end{tabular}%
}
\setlength{\headheight}{22pt} % check the log to be sure what this length should be

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}
\chapter{This is my first chapter}
\section{With my section}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

The value for `\headheight` can be determined by `fancyhdr` itself: first leave the line commented out; then check in the `.log` file, where the required value is shown.

[image]