# Fancyhead and subsections

Tags: fancyhdr, article

I just started to use `fancyhead`.

I have encountered a problem that my subsection titles are placed on the same row as the header. If the subsection title is too long, the two shunks of text will be printed above each other.

One such example:
[image]

I would be happy with any of the two solutions:

1. Remove the subsection title from the headers
2. Make sure the subsectoin title and the header made by me will be on different rows. Some kind of solution with a table perhaps - as in [Getting chapter and section in \fancyhead](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113661/getting-chapter-and-section-in-fancyhead).

I will attach my dummy code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}    
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[R]{Studiehandledning \date{\today}}

\title{Studiehandledning till kursen \\
xxxxx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage

\section{bla bla}

\lipsum

\subsection{skalleper}

\lipsum

\section{wlä wlä wlä}

\lipsum

\section{olika oolika ffgfd rgrgreg rgdsfgdsfgrd gsdgsdg  gsrgrg}

\lipsum

\subsection{olika oolika ffgfd rgrgreg rgdsfgdsfgrd gsdgsdg  gsrgrg}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

One peculiarity is also that only subsections show up in the header, not sections. But that migh be related to the discussion regarding even and odd pages in [Getting chapter and section in \fancyhead](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113661/getting-chapter-and-section-in-fancyhead).

Comment: Not sure what you want, as  your points 1 and 2 are a bit contradictory. Do you want or not a subsection title? What about  section titles?

Comment: It is not for the purpose of this report necessary. Therefore two options. The section titles do not appear in the header - as I wrote. Maybe it is due to this odd/even page thing. I'm not sure.

Comment: But what do *you* want to have, exactly?

Comment: It is more about what I do not want to have. I do not want have text intrefering/overlapping my intended header.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code does what you want (only *your* header, and the page number):

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{Studiehandledning \date{\today}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
```

*Added:*

I propose this, using the optional argument of (sub)section when the title is too long, if it makes sense. I think it's simpler to do it with `titleps`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, swedish]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}

 \usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{mine}{%
\large
\headrule
\sethead[\itshape\thesection.\enspace\MakeUppercase{\sectiontitle}][][\itshape Studiehandledning \date{\today}]%
{\itshape Studiehandledning \date{\today}}{}{\itshape\thesubsection\enspace\subsectiontitle}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}%

\title{Studiehandledning till kursen \\
xxxxx}
\pagestyle{mine}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage

\section{bla bla}

\lipsum

\subsection{skalleper}

\lipsum

\section{wlä wlä wlä}

\lipsum

\section[olika oolika grrrumph]{olika ffgfd rgrgreg rgdsfgdsfgrd gsdgsdg gsrgrg}

\lipsum

\subsection[olika oolika pfffyiæð]
{olika oolika ffgfd rgrgreg rgdsfgdsfgrd gsdgsdg gsrgrg}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

This code works only for two-sided documents, because of the use of the 3 optional arguments of `\sethead`.

*Added 2*: For one-sided documents, you can obtain the same result with the `\ifoddpage` package and this code:

```
\usepackage{isoddpage}

\sethead{\itshape Studiehandledning \date{\today}}{}%
{\checkoddpage%
 \itshape\ifoddpage\thesubsection\enspace\subsectiontitle\else\thesection.\enspace\MakeUppercase{\sectiontitle}\fi}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}%
```

Comment: Yes, this indeed is "Solution 1"! Does `\fancyhf{}` mean that any other headers shouldbe ignored?

Comment: I presume that "Solution 2" is much trickier?

Comment: You want subsections  titles  and your text on the same page? What  about section titles? Do they go somewhere, or there should be none? Is it for a twosided or a onesided document?

Comment: To make life simple, let's answer yes on your first question. Yes, as I said, I do not know why the section titles doesn't show up in the test example. Let us assume it is single sided for simplicity - or does it make it harder?

Comment: I'd say it's easier with `titleps` (which comes with `titlesec`) as one doe not have to struggle with marks. I'll post a code in a moment. Are the lengths of your subsections realistic? You might use the optional argument to have shorter titles.

Comment: It depends on the margins of the document as well. Recently I made the margins to look more like a Word default document, and now the problems seems to be much less. But it is an interesting question, and in many cases you are not as free to chose margins as I am in this case.

Comment: Loading `geometry` without any option already makes more deceny margins (unless you have substantial marginal notes). Does it make sense to use the optional argument of section titles in order to have a short form for the headers?

Comment: True about `geometry`. I am not sure whether or not I understand your question. Do you mean that one should introduce abbreviations of section and subsection titles?

Comment: I would say so, if  it makes sense.

Comment: Your working example worked fine, but when I removed the `fancyhdr` part and put in the `titleps` things instead in my "real document", no headers appeared at all. Can it be some compatibility problems with some package I use?

Comment: Except of course  with `fancyhdr` since tickle the same things, I don't see. Maybe the .cls file itf it's not one of the standard classes? Do you have error messages, and could you post a minimal (non-)working example?

Comment: A bit shameful, bit it showed to be a user mistake. Thanks! I'll play with this an see if everything will work as desired

Comment: No problem. Everyone does mistakes!

Comment: Some followup: (1) Can you have a `oneside` document (to get the pagenumbering at the same places etc) but still have every second header different? (2) The abbreviations of the sections you spoke about, how does that take place - I do not think it is automatically done by the code example you gave? (3) In MS Word you can have multirow headers, is that more or less forbidden in LaTeX?

Comment: (1): No, it won't. I've posted another code  for one sided documents  (2) You have to do it byhand, with a code like `\section[short title]{A much longer title}`.  (3) You put everything want in the header (except floats…): images, tables. Usually, you'll have to change the value of `\headheight`. It might be at the cost of a rape of typographical rules.